# Change the UIComponent Style programmatically through actionListener does not work

Tags: jsf, facelets, actionevent

In my JSF project i have a static navigation tree with multiple commandLinks like :

```
            <h:commandLink id="navlinksearchperson"
                action="#{bean.someAction}"
                value="#{messages['menu.person']}"
                actionListener="#{styleBean.changeSelection}">
            </h:commandLink>
```

The action listener looks like this:

```
@RequestScoped
@Named("styleBean")
public class StyleBean {

    public void changeSelection(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getComponent() instanceof HtmlCommandLink) {
            ((HtmlCommandLink) event.getComponent()).setStyle("font-weight : bold; color : white");
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to a achieve is to highlight the the link(s) which has been clicked so the user sees exactly which navigation link/path is currently viewed. The event will be invoked but the style is not set/rendered.

Does I miss something or is the ActionEvent not in the right phase to set attributes of the UIComponent?

**Update:**
The action looks like this:

```
public String init() {
    if (conversation.isTransient()) {
        conversation.begin();
    } 

    /*
     * Service call for request query
     */

    return "/views/list.xhtml";
}
```

Comment: That can happen if the action is recreating the view instead of returning to the same view (by returning a non-`null`/`void` outcome).

Comment: @BalusC I've added the action I'm using ... the view ID will be returned ... is the conversation a problem in this case?